# How to write "Art" in Excel without it automaticaly adding "." at the end?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Starting with ' doesn't help nor does changing cell category. Excel is just adamant in adding a dot at the end of the word "Art".

EDIT: Answer by harrymc

> Check File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect options if you have added the automatic replacement of "Art" by "Art.", perhaps in the Math AutoCorrect tab.

Comment: So, you type "Art" in a cell, and you say that a period is added to the end of it? Does this happen with other words? Are you using a Mac or PC?

Comment: Check *File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect options* if you have added the automatic replacement of "Art" by "Art.", perhaps in the Math AutoCorrect tab.

Comment: Thanks harrymc, it worked

Comment: @DumbGuy,,, it's brave attempt when you try to post an answer for your own post,, but what U have done is not the correct way,, plzz [edit] your post and delete portion suggested by #harrymc, and post it as an Answer,

Answer (score 0):

Go to *C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates*

Change the ***normal.dotm*** file to ***normal.dotm.old*** and restart Word, Word automatically creates a new version (which uses the original default settings) the next time that you start Word. The new version will not include any of the customizations that you made to the version that you renamed or moved.